# Html Форма и ее php оброботчик

Tags: php, html, mysql, form

Есть форма (текстовое поле textarea)..
В моей форме допустим Вы написали:

```
 Привет
 <--- MORE --->
 Вася
```

И вот нужно чтоб слово 'привет' записалось в одну таблицу бд, а второе 'Вася' в другую..
Тоесть чтоб скрипт все содержимое поля до тега MORE записывал в одну таблицу, а содержимое после этого тега в другую..
Типа как в WordPress, до тега описание, после тега продолжение статьи (при нажатии на кнопку ' Читать дальше... ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "Привет
<--- MORE --->
Вася";
$part = explode("<--- MORE --->", $text);
echo $part[0]; // часть1
echo $part[1]; // часть2
```

Далее переменную $part[0] пишешь в одну таблицу, а $part[1] в другую